# How to make OAuth2 server read client from database rather than write in memory?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-oauth2

So I want to find a way to **read** Client credentials (client_id, client_secret,...) from database. I'm currently using SpringBoot 2.7.3.
Every tutorial I found is from 4+ years ago and use deprecated dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using the `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` implementation of the `ClientRegistrationRepository` interface. If you want to retrieve the clients from another place, you have to create a new implementation of that interface. If you are using Spring Data JPA, you can do something like:

```java
public interface ClientRegistrationSpringDataRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientRegistrationEntity, String> { 

}

@Repository
public class DaoClientRegistrationRepository implement ClientRegistrationRepository {

    private final ClientRegistrationSpringDataRepository repository;

    // constructor

    @Override
    public ClientRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        ClientRegistrationEntity entity = this.repository.getById(registrationId);
        return mapToClientRegistration(entity);
    }

    private ClientRegistration mapToClientRegistration(ClientRegistrationEntity entity) {
        // your logic
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new, I have follow your guide, what do you mean by "your logic".

Comment: Because we are using JPA in this scenario and the JPA entity is different from Spring Security's `ClientRegistration`, you should map from one object to another in order to return the right type

Comment: But isn't this just make a new implementation? I still can't import my database into the oauth2 server right? There used to be clientdetailsserviceconfigurer but now deprecated.

Comment: Yes, it is a new implementation, Spring Security does not have yet an out-of-the-box `ClientRegistrationRepository` implementation that looks up the database, you have to create your own. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/core.html#oauth2Client-client-registration-repo

Comment: Sorry.... So all I have to do is write the code above and map them correct and that's it? It will be able to access Clients in DB and authorize them?